# Breaking out of a while loop when hitting a duplicate

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
steps = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'F']]

for step in steps:

    while True:
        last_item = ""

        for item in step:
            if item != last_item: 
                print(item)
                last_item = item
            else:
                break
```

The desired result is for the loop to print A, then B, then C, but when hitting the first duplicate C it should move on to printing D, then E, then F, and then stop when hitting the first duplicate F.

This is a minimal reproducible example of a loop to be used in a web scraping job, so solutions that involve doing `set(steps)`or other operations on the example `steps` as such will not solve it. My question has to to with the architecture of the loop.

Comment: Can you have a set of seen elements and the print only if not in `seen`?

Comment: Comment `while true` and it should work in the way you want. Check [this](https://onlinegdb.com/r13g1TdbV)

Comment: What is going wrong with your code at the moment? If you move the while loop outside `for step in steps:` then it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option with while loop, accessing objects by index:

```
steps = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'F']]

i = 0
ii = 0
memo = []
res = []
while True:
  if i == len(steps): break
  e = steps[i][ii]
  if e in memo:
    res.append(memo)
    memo = []
    ii = 0
    i += 1
  else:
    memo.append(e)
    print(e)
    ii += 1
```

It prints out:

```
# A
# B
# C
# D
# E
# F
```

While res value is:

```
print(res) #=> [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
steps = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'F']]

for step in steps:
  last_item = ""

  for item in step:
      if item != last_item: 
          print(item)
          last_item = item
      else:
          break
```

When you keep `while true` and break is encountered from inner for loop, control will never pass to outer for loop for getting next item

> (['D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'F'])

in outer list, creating infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You do **not** need `while True`. Except for that part your code works as expected:

```
steps = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'F']]

for step in steps:

    # while True:
        last_item = ""

        for item in step:
            if item != last_item:
                print(item)
                last_item = item
            else:
                break
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this while loop from your code. [break] below works in this loop. To achieve your desired output, [break] need to break the for loop above.

```
steps = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'F']]

for step in steps:

# while True:
    last_item = ""

    for item in step:
        if item != last_item:
            print(item)
            last_item = item
        else:
            break
```